# How to apply a data template to a ListBox?

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, wpf-controls

I have a ListBox, when an event occur outside the ListBox (ex click on a button) I need to apply

```
CategoriesUnselectedDataTemplate
```

to the element of the `CategoriesListBox`

Anyidea how to solve this?

```
        <Custom:SurfaceListBox
                x:Name="CategoriesListBox"
                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                ManipulationDelta="CategoriesListBox_ManipulationDelta"
                IsManipulationEnabled="True"
                SelectionChanged="CategoriesListBox_SelectionChanged"
                ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource CategoriesUnselectedDataTemplate}"
                VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                SelectionMode="Single"
                Margin="115,131,-117,-49">
        </Custom:SurfaceListBox>



    <DataTemplate x:Key="CategoriesUnselectedDataTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Name="titleCategory" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                           Text="{Binding CapitalizedDescription, FallbackValue=CategoryName}"
                           Foreground="#2fb8dc"
                           FontFamily="/GateeClientWPF;component/Fonts/#Letter Gothic L"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           FontSize="30"
                           Margin="0,10"/>
            <Image Source="Assets/common/right_grey.png" Width="20" Height="20" Visibility="Visible" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" d:LayoutOverrides="Height" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Look at the [DataTemplateSelector Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: could you provide me an alternative approach?

Comment: Why you want an alternative approach?